# Alias pods in CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods

Is it possible to create an alias in a Podfile?

For context, my Podfile looks something like this:

```rb
target 'myApp' do

  platform :ios, '9.0'

  pod 'react-native-branch', path: "../node_modules/react-native-branch"
  pod 'Branch-SDK', path: "../node_modules/react-native-branch/ios"
  pod 'Segment-Branch'

  pod 'Stripe', '~> 11.2.0'

end
```

The `Segment-Branch` pod installs a `Branch` pod as a dependency, and this pod is essentially the same as `Branch-SDK`. I am getting errors about duplicate declarations when building, and unfortunately my hands are a bit tied and it seems I need to reference the `Branch-SDK` pod.

Is there a way I can **alias** a `pod 'Branch'` to `Branch-SDK`?

Alternatively, is there anyway to control the configuration on the `pod 'Segment-Branch'` side of things? Perhaps something with a `:podspec`, `path`, or `subspecs:[]` configuration?

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I'm encountering the same problem

Comment: The same here. I'm using sub-projects with multiple Pods.xcodeproj in the same .xcworkspace, these sub-projects use different versions of the same Pod...